# Differentiability at the boundary points

Tags: limits, derivatives

I studied that differentiability at a point is confirmed if the left hand derivative is equal to the right hand derivative in open interval (a,b).  Now the confusion is at the boundary points how can we define the left hand derivative for left boundary point and the right hand derivative for right boundary point?
Is differentiability even defines at these points? If not why?

Comment: Right and left derivatives are defined, as you say. You can call the points right and left differentiable respectively.

Comment: How do we prove it at the boundary points

Comment: .Sorry, read your post again. If the left boundary point has a right derivative then it is right differentiable at that point. It need have no left such limit to be right differentiable. Typically though, many theorems in real analysis only concern differentiability in the open interval and are not concerned with behaviour at the boundary.

Comment: So we do not comment about left boundary point's left hand derivative

Comment: Standard definition: $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ if $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and the right and left derivatives of $f$ exist at $a,b$ respectively.